# How can I add a second color effect to an object in Adobe Animate CC

Tags: effects, adobe-animate

I have a problem with Adobe Animate CC and I'm an absolute newbie.

I use symbols and I want them to undergo different changes, one after the other. These are:

- fade in (used the color effect style "Alpha" to accomplish it)
- change color to red (tried using color effect style "Hue", but this doesn't work).

**What I've tried:**

- I use two keyframes to build the fade-in effect (Alpha channel).
- I set one color keyframe (to preserve the original color).
- Then I add another color keyframe at the place in the timeline I want the change to be finished.
- I change the color in the second ("red") keyframe so that the color should shift from original to red.

**My problem:**

Once I change the color in the "red" keyframe all other keyframes (including the Alpha keyframes) disappear.

**My question:**
Is there any way to add a second (or third) animation of this kind without having to duplicate the object?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can apply both color (tint) and alpha changes to symbols (Movieclips and Graphics) but you have to do them separately - there need to be two timelines - one symbol is inside another symbol. You control the opacity on the parent symbol and the tinting on the child symbol.

1. So you need to make a graphic symbol - let's say a blue circle by creating a circle and creating a symbol of it (F8) and giving it an instance name - "blue-yellow-circle" - click "OK".
2. While "blue-yellow-circle" is still selected on the stage, make it a symbol again (F8) and give it another instance name - "opaque-circle-transp". So now you have a graphic symbol inside another graphic symbol.

Here's the structure:
Stage
 - opaque-circle-transp
  - blue-yellow-circle

3. Each symbol has a timeline, just like the stage or root. So now you need to create an animation in the "opaque-circle-transp" symbol by setting the "blue-yellow-circle" symbol's tint. So let's say you make the animation 30 frames. You can leave the 1st keyframe alone - i.e. no tint. Create a keyframe at frame 30 and set it to a particular tint. Now create a "Classic Tween" between these keyframes by right-clicking in the frames between the keyframes and selecting "Create Classic Tween".
4. Now go to one of your keyframes (1 or 30) and double-click your circle symbol. you should now be within the symbol "blue-yellow-circle". Create a keyframe at frame 30 and designate the alpha to what you want. Now create a tween by right-clicking and selecting "Create Classic Tween".

You can now go out to the root or stage level and you should still have 30 frames. Now if you test the animation, the symbol should transition from blue and opaque to yellow and transparent.

An alternative to this would be to use shapes (only if the shapes are fairly simple and similar shapes). You can do this all in one timeline if you set the color and opacity of the shape for each of the two keyframes and create a "Shape Tween" between the keyframes.

I hope this is helpful.

Answer (score 0):

There is a much simpler solution: use ["**Advanced**"](http://www.adobepress.com/articles/article.asp?p=1311989&seqNum=4) instead of "Tint". This will allow you to animate color and alpha channel simultaneously.